# Too many re-renders with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-hooks

Similar questions have been asked but I haven't found a solution for this particular one. I have one component which renders all boards and I am using a custom `useFetch` hook to fetch all boards.

```js
const BoardsDashboard = () => {

  let [boards, setBoards] = useState([]);

  const { response } = useFetch(routes.BOARDS_INDEX_URL, {});

  setBoards(response);

  return (
    <main className="dashboard">
      <section className="board-group">
        <header>
          <div className="board-section-logo">
            <span className="person-logo"></span>
          </div>
          <h2>Personal Boards</h2>
        </header>

        <ul className="dashboard-board-tiles">
          {boards.map(board => (
            <BoardTile title={board.title} id={board.id} key={board.id} />
          ))}
          <CreateBoardTile />
        </ul>
    
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

const useFetch = (url, options) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(url, options);
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return { response, error };
};
```

I am getting too many re-renders due to `setBoards(response)` line. What is the right way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Sounds like you might want a useEffect hook to take action when response is updated.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setBoards(response);
}, [response]);
```

Note: if you have no need to ever change the `boards` state, then maybe it doesn’t need to be stateful at all, you could just use the returned value from your `useFetch` hook and be done with it.

```
const { response: boards } = useFetch(...);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. Can you tell me how come this works, but when I was trying to do this:



`
useEffect(() => {
    async () => {
      const { response } = await useFetch(routes.BOARDS_INDEX_URL, {});
      setBoards(response);
    }
  }, [])
```

I was getting invalid use of hooks error ?

Comment: Hooks have to be at the top level, can’t be nested inside other hooks. The reason my solution works is because the effect will only be run when response changes. Since response only changes on your initial useFetch execution, the effect will only fun that one time.

Comment: Is your solution considered a "hack" then, or it is proper React code that should be used?
Thank you once again

Comment: My code is considered correct, although depending on your use case it’s hard to tell why you’d need to maintain boards in state when you could simply use the response from useFetch as the boards.